# How can I be getting java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm going to kick myself all over when I find out the answer, but I'm baffled, so:

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` reported by (some) users when trying to access OneDrive. Of course I can't reproduce it myself. I'm using Microsoft's OneDrive SDK. `FileListItem` is my class that I'm trying to populate in the `success()` method of the SDK's callback. The location of the error comes from the stack trace in the Google Play developer console error details.

```
final ICallback<IItemCollectionPage> callback = new ICallback<IItemCollectionPage>() {
    @Override
    public void success(final IItemCollectionPage result) {
        for (Item child : result.getCurrentPage()) {
            FileListItem item = new FileListItem();
            item.name = child.name;
            if (child.parentReference != null) {
                item.sourcePath = child.parentReference.path;  // java.lang.NullPointerException
            }
            ...
```

So `child` comes from the `for` loop through the (presumably valid) list passed to `success()`, it doesn't crash on `child.name`, and `child.parentReference != null`.

My question is if `item` is a valid object that I've just created, and `child.parentReference != null`, how can those users be getting a `NullPointerException`?

Edited to add the full stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at [myapp].OneDriveProvider$4.success (OneDriveProvider.java:183)
  at [myapp].OneDriveProvider$4.success (OneDriveProvider.java:176)
  at com.onedrive.sdk.concurrency.DefaultExecutors$1.run (DefaultExecutors.java:88)
  at com.onedrive.sdk.concurrency.SynchronousExecutor$1.onPostExecute (SynchronousExecutor.java:54)
  at com.onedrive.sdk.concurrency.SynchronousExecutor$1.onPostExecute (SynchronousExecutor.java:46)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish (AsyncTask.java:755)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900 (AsyncTask.java:192)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage (AsyncTask.java:772)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7397)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Sure, added it to the question.

Comment: If the NPE was thrown on line `item.sourcePath = child.parentReference.path`. The only reason is that `child.parentReference` is set to `null` by another thread. You should check if this could happen, and I suggest synchronising these lines.